# Location manager is not working in iOS8

Tags: ios, iphone, delegates, core-location, cllocationmanager

Please don't mark it as duplicate because I took help from others posted answer in stack overflow. But still I faced some issues. Location manager delegate not get called even in real device also. And also it's not asking for the permission.

Below is my code.

```
- (IBAction)getUserLocationAction:(id)sender
{
    if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])
    {
        if(!locationManager)
            locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

        [locationManager setDelegate:self];
        [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];

        if ([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
            [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
        }

        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
        //[locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Location service is not enabled");
    }
}


#pragma mark - Location Manager Delegate- 

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    NSLog(@"%@", locations);
    userLocation = [locations lastObject];
    NSLog(@"User Current Locatiion\nLat: %+.6f\nLong: %+.6f", [userLocation coordinate].latitude, [userLocation coordinate].longitude);

   [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
   //[locationManager stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
}



- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

I also add the below two key in my .plist file

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app want to use your location</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app want to use your location</string>
```

I have also added the frameworks

[image]

I am not sure where I am doing wrong. Please help me.

> **UPDATE**

Firstly I think its an issue with my code but after some research it's working as expected in iOS7. The code is remain same, this issue occur only in iOS8. Please let me know what changes needs to be done for working in iOS8 also.

Comment: Where are you handling the call back when the user is accepting you app to use the location?

Comment: it's not asking any kind of permission.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the line `[locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];` and see if it get called.

Comment: Yes it's get called.

Comment: just have a look at [here](http://idiotswithios.blogspot.in/2015/02/get-user-current-location.html).
I have not implemented step 7

Comment: Check the status of the location manager: `[CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]` and act accordingly

Comment: @rckoenes it's pointing `kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined`. So now what I have to do?

Comment: `NSLog(@"%d",[CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]);` check what is the output

Comment: Is location services enabled on your device?  Have you previously denied location permission to this app (check the privacy->Location Services->Your app name settings)? How is your global variable `locationManager` defined?

Comment: @UtkarshSingh firstly I used only `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` then used `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` then I put both but nothing happen in any scenario.

Comment: @Paulw11 `@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager *locationManager;` and I haven't get any confirmation alert to deny or allow.

Comment: Then you should refer to the property `self.locationManager`, not the iVar `locationManager`

Comment: @Paulw11 why? I use `@synthesize locationManager`. Anyways I follow your instruction but no output.

Comment: Your code will work perfectly (if all the things mentioned above is correct). Either you didn't enabled the location service for your app, or the method is not working. Also `kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined` won't be the result. Check that once again. If you did all the above mentioned things, just reset the simulator and check

Comment: It won't fix your problem (see @MidhunMP's comment - your code looks right, so try deleting your app/restarting the device/simulator) but it is matter of good style.  You should only bypass property setter/getters when you have a good reason

Comment: @MidhunMP I have followed every step you all are suggesting me. Also reset the simulator and xCode too but still I am in the same place.

Comment: @TapasPal: I created a new project copy pasted your code, added the keys in plist and called `getUserLocationAction` from viewDidLoad. Everything works perfectly for me. So I don't think it's issue with your code (I hope you added the core location framework and included the header file).

Comment: @MidhunMP I created another project and use the same code. Why it's not working for me. Is there any problem with my xCode? I am getting frustrated.

Comment: For those who are down voting my question, can you help me out??

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some more checking:

```
- (IBAction)getUserLocationAction:(id)sender
{
    if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) {

        if(!self.locationManager) {
            self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
            [self.locationManager setDelegate:self];
            [self.locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
        }

        CLAuthorizationStatus authStatus = [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];
        if (authStatus == kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
            // Check for iOS 8 method
            if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
                [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
            }
            else {
                [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
            }
        }
        else if(authStatus == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways || authStatus == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse || authStatus == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
            [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
        }
        else if(authStatus == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied){
            NSLog(@"User did not allow location tracking.");
            // present some dialog that you want the location.
        }
        else {
            // kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted
            // restriction on the device do not allow location tracking.
        }
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Location service is not enabled");
    }
}
```

Also you need to handle the use callback:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status {
    if (status != kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted &&  status !=kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied) {
        [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }
}
```

Comment: I have changed as you posted.. in `getUserLocationAction` it's not logged anything. And it's called `didChangeAuthorizationStatus` and the `status = kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined ` coming.

Comment: Facing this issue only in iOS8, working fine in iOS7

Answer (score 0):

Check your Location Access settings..so go to Setting-->Privacy-->Location Services-->Your app

Comment: My app is not listed under  `Setting-->Privacy-->Location Services`

Comment: k....i think you should check this link  http://nevan.net/2014/09/core-location-manager-changes-in-ios-8/   , briefly describe location services changes in  ios 8

Comment: I took help from this site also. If you can check my code you will understand. I thing I am missing something because my code looks good and also MidhunMP got success by using my code. God knows what happen.